# Probability of product being greater that or equal to $\frac{18}{25}$times the greatest product

Tags: probability, permutations

Given the sum of two non negative integers as $100$, the find the probability that their product is greater that or equal to $\frac{18}{25}$times their greatest possible product.

Greatest possible product is $2500$. So if numbers are $x$ and $y$, then we need $xy \geq 1800$ but how are we supposed to calculate favorable and total cases?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let numbers be $50-x$ and $50+x$ so  product of number will be $(50-x)(50+x)$. This is a decreasing function, maximum at $x=0$. So just solve $(50-x)(50+x)\ge 1800$

$$x^2 \le 2500-1800 = 700$$
This gives us $x\in [0,26]$ as $x$ is integer.

Comment: So it means we have 53 favorable cases and 101 total cases.

Comment: Yes I think that it is. $26*2 + 1$.

Answer (score 1):

The total cases are
$$
x = 0, y = 100\\
x = 1, y = 99\\
\vdots\\
x = 100, y = 0
$$
For favourable cases, you just need to count how many of these have $xy\geq 1800$. It can be nice to know that the closer $x$ and $y$ are to one another, the larger their product becomes. This way you only have to test a fraction of the total cases to find all the favourable ones.